# Anything Slider prevent infinite thumbnail carousel loop

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I am using JQuery Anything Slider / PHP / MySQL. Everything is working as expected in my code. However I would like to disable the back arrow of the thumbnail carousel if you're displaying the first set of thumbnail. I would also like to disable the forward if you're displaying the last set of thumbnail from the image set. In other word I want to prevent the thumbnail carousel from looping indefinitely. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<div class="anythingSlider">
            <div class="thumb_wrapper">
              <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <?php 
                $new = 1; 
                $count = 0; 
                do { 
                    if ($new == 1)
                        {echo '<li style="list-style-type: none;">';} ?> <div class="thumb" data-count="<?php echo $count; ?>" data-thumb="<?php echo $image_row['thumb']; ?>"   ><img title="<?php echo $image_row['description']; ?>" data-image="<?php echo $image_row['image']; ?>" src="<?php echo $image_row['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_row['description']; ?>" /></div>
                <?php $count++; 
                        if ($new == 5)
                        { echo "</li>"; $new = 1;
                        } else {
                            $new ++;}
                    } 
                while ($image_row = mysql_fetch_array($image));  ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Additional information... Here are my Anything Slider options.

```
function formatText(index, panel) {
              return index + "";
          };

        $(function () {

            $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
                easing: "easeInOutExpo",            
                autoPlay: false,                    
                delay: 3000,                        
                startStopped: false,                
                animationTime: 600,                 
                hashTags: true,                     
                buildNavigation: true,              
                pauseOnHover: true,                 
                startText: "Go",                    
                stopText: "Stop",                   
                navigationFormatter: formatText     
            });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/1507/)? Basically just set the `infiniteSlides` option to `false` and `stopAtEnd` to `true`

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    infiniteSlides: false,
    stopAtEnd: true
});
```